As Vesta Was From Latmos Hill Descending
In Thomas Weelkes' "As Vesta Was From Latmos Hill Descending", why are the servants of Vesta called Diana's darlings?
The lyrics:

As Vesta was from Latmos hill descending,
She spied a maiden Queen the same ascending,
Attended on by all the shepherds' swain,
To whom Diana's darlings came running down amain,
First two by two, then three by three together,
Leaving their goddess all alone hasted thither;
And mingling with the shepherds of her train,
With mirthful tunes her presence entertain.
Then sang the shepherds and nymphs of Diana,
Long live fair Oriana!

